# How to get image file name from MySQL record?

Tags: php, mysql

I have images as records in `question_answers` table.

Images storing `<span style="font-family:'MS Reference Sans Serif'"><span style="font-size:9pt"><img width="51" height="32" align="bottom" alt="mc001-2.jpg" src="@@PLUGINFILE@@/mc001-2.jpg" border="0"></span></span>`

How to get image name `mc001-2.jpg` from here using PHP and MySQL?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_match()`:-

```
<?php

$str = '<span style="font-family:MS Reference Sans Serif"><span style="font-size:9pt"><img width="51" height="32" align="bottom" alt="mc001-2.jpg" src="@@PLUGINFILE@@/mc001-2.jpg" border="0"></span></span>';
preg_match('/alt="(.*?)"/', $str, $out);

//see first output
echo ($out[1]);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/399769

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$conn = mysqli_query('server name','user name','password','database name') or die(mysqli_connect_error());
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"Select answer from question_answers") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$img_name_array = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >0){

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
          $image_data = $row['answer'];
          preg_match('/alt="(.*?)"/',$str, $out);
          $img_name_array[] = $out[1];
    }

}else{

echo "no record exist"; 
}
```

Note:- `$img_name_array` will contain all the images name.Thanks.

Comment: look into my attached table, want to get all the names from `answer` column.

Comment: your code is not working, please guide me how can use foreach with your code. PLZ

Comment: i already puted it in `while() loop`. after that you can use `foreach()` on `$img_name_array` if you want to show or do some work on that.

Comment: Got all the images names by using your first suggestion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83414/discussion-between-raja-and-anant-kumar-singh).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT image_name FROM question_answers
WHERE image_name LIKE '%mc001-2.jpg%';
```

If I have interpreted your question correctly it means you are storing HTML in your MySQL table. I hope I am wrong.

Comment: not only one record. having more records like this, need to get all the images(records) names.

Comment: Simply `SELECT image_name FROM question_answers;` If your column is called `image_name` of course.

Comment: look into my attached table, want to get all the names from `answer` column.